# TableView inside ScrollView

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want tableView [50,50,200,300] in scrollView[0,0,1024,1400] for iPad in Landscape mode. ScrollView is scrolling fine where as table view in scrollView does not takes touches to scroll.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 5):

What behavior would you expect from this?

Having two embedded scrolling element within a screen I guess is confusing.  More specifically apple state:

> [Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: I would expect that the embedded scroll view(s) would capture the touch events that they handle, rather than allowing them to continue propagating to the enclosing scroll view.  We're not talking about a completely alien paradigm here.  It's certainly no issue to have nested scrollable elements in a webpage, for instance.